# Romanian Programmers keyboard layout using AutoHotkey

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, keyboard-layout

I would like to enable the [Romanian Programmers](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/keyboards/kbdropr.html) keyboard layout with AutoHotKey because I need to use some applications which have certain shortcuts that overlap with "unusual" layouts and having Right Alt transformed into AltGr is not acceptable.

Please see my answer for a working solution, and feel free to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script that I ended up using:

```
;Disable the Right Alt key (the keydown event will still be fired, but that's OK)
RAlt::Return

RAlt & a::
    if GetKeyState("Shift", "P") {
        Send Ă
    } else {
        Send ă
    }
    Return

RAlt & q::
    if GetKeyState("Shift", "P") {
        Send Â
    } else {
        Send â
    }
    Return

RAlt & i::
    if GetKeyState("Shift", "P") {
        Send Î
    } else {
        Send î
    }
    Return

RAlt & s::
    if GetKeyState("Shift", "P") {
        Send Ș
    } else {
        Send ș
    }
    Return

RAlt & t::
    if GetKeyState("Shift", "P") {
        Send Ț
    } else {
        Send ț
    }
    Return

RAlt & e::Send €

RAlt & c::Send ©
```

Please note that I have only mapped the keys that I needed from the Romanian Programmers layout, which has a few more shortcuts for uncommon symbols.